# Math.abs in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am confused with math.abs().
I did Research through internet but couldn't find any relation with this bouncing ball's animation. I want to know how this works and how ball is bouncing smoothly after using math.abs() function?

```
function bounce() {
    if (x + dx > 293 || x + dx < 0) {
        dx = -dx;
    }
    if (y >= 290) {
        y = 290;
    }
    if (y + dy > 290 || y + dy < 0) {
        dx *= 0.99;
        dy = -dy;
    }
    //if (Math.abs(dx) < 0.01) {
       // dx = 0;
    }
    dy++;
}
```

I did **comment** the line confusing me. Anyone please let me know that how important this function for this animation.

### Fiddle

Comment: Are you asking exactly what that function does? Or why it is used?

Comment: @Tom Walters : How this function works?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`dx` is the displacement on x.

`Math.abs(dx)` is the absolute speed on x, that is the value without the sign, always positive or null.

```
if (Math.abs(dx) < 0.01) {
```

could have been written as

```
if (dx>-0.01 && dx < 0.01) {
```

Basically, this line with the following one stops the ball along `x` if it's already slow.

Answer (score 3):

dx is reduced by 1% every time the last condition is met (`if (y + dy > 290 || y + dy < 0) {`)

this calculation can go on forever but would yield jagged results because the floating point precision errors would become a large factor compared to dx so better stop the ball bouncing when it is already slow which is what the test using Math-abs is for. In english you could read

```
if (Math.abs(dx) < 0.01)
```

as `if the speed of the ball in the x direction is less than 0.01 then stop the ball`