# responsive content positioned incorrectly on first load

Tags: responsive-design

My website content loads further down the page than expected on initial load.

The name and other content appear in the middle of the page, instead of the top.

If I grab the browser corner, and resize the window - even slightly - the content pops back to the top of the page.

I'm unsure of what's causing this.

I've tested on Chrome/Safari/FF on Mac Desktop
The response is normal on a tablet or smartphone

The page is at http://www.mac-works.com/dev/MG/mark3

Notice on first load, Michael's name is in the middle of the page, but if you grab the lower corner and move - everything pops to the top where it's supposed to be

I'm aware there are a number of other posts about responsive content, I've reviewed more than 20, but none seem to address the content not loading properly on first load, but correcting when the browser is resized.

Comment: I'm in FF and don't see anything pop back to the top?

Comment: So his name loads at the top of the page, the first time you bring it up?  For me, his name loads in the middle of the screen.  That's not what I want.

Comment: The problem is with `.filtr_bg`'s inline `margin-top` / `margin-bottom` styles. Where and when is this applied? Therein lies your problem.

Comment: Actually, I see it. It's at the very top of `js.js` script file. Need some modification there.

Comment: Any more detail you can offer?  I agree it's the margin top/bottom.  I was trying to correct in the css-which didn't work.   Someone else created the js for me since I'm not all that familiar with it

Comment: I agree that's the cause. If I comment that line out in the js.js - the name appears correctly at the top of the page - but then the links don't work.   Any thoughts?

Comment: Which links don't work? It appears to be working for me at the dev link you sent

Comment: Turns out it was var marg_top = Math.abs((body_h - container_h)/12); in js.js as you said.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was the var marg_top = Math.abs  function.  Intially set to /2 - I changed it to /8 moved the content up towards the top.

So, if you're using floating content with javascript - make sure you're familiar with the math.abs function.

[Math.abs in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750182/math-abs-in-javascript)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/math_abs.htm